# Error while sign up in simple file login program

Tags: c

I already asked before and have done something that would work i think (but i'm a beginner so that story falls into a water) i have an error when i tried to sign up can anyone help? I have few more hours to send it (homework) AND i don't ask someone to do it for me, just to gimme instructions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int signIn(char username[30], char pass[30]){

FILE *p;
char user2[30], pass2[30];

p = fopen("users.txt", "r+");


fscanf(p,"%s\n%s",user2,pass2);

if( (strcmp(username,user2)==0) && (strcmp(pass,pass2)==0) )
    printf("\nUser and password correct!!!");
else
    printf("\nUser or password incorrect!\n\n");

printf("\n\n");

fclose(p);
return 0;
}

int signUp(char username[30], char pass[30], char fullName[30]) {

FILE *p;
p = fopen("users.txt", "r+");

printf("Username: ");
scanf("%s", &username);

printf("Password: ");
scanf("%s", &pass);

printf("Full name: ");
scanf("%s", &fullName);

fprintf(p, "%s\n%s\n%s", username, fullName, pass);

fclose(p);
return 0;
}

int main(){
char username[30], pass[30], fullName[30];
int choose;

printf("Welcome to student login system!\n");
printf(" 1: Sign in\n 2: Sign up\n");
printf("--------------------------------\n");
scanf("%d", &choose);

if(choose==1) {
    printf("\nUser:");
    scanf("%s",username);
    printf("\nPassword:");
    scanf("%s",pass);
    signIn(username, pass);
}

if(choose==2) {

    signUp(username, pass, fullName);

}

}
```

I tried a lot different ways and i'm really confused right now..

Comment: You need to read every line in "users.txt" when checking if a sign-in is correct. You are currently only checking the first line of the file.

Comment: what error do you encounter with signup

Comment: @JoshKisb after entering full name program stopped working i think in line fprintf(p, "%s\n%s\n%s", username, fullName, pass);

Comment: well after entering name it is the end of your program. you can go ahead to check if contents were written to file but that is done in background

Comment: oh also you intend to write to file its w+ not r+

Comment: See my last comment to your last question.

Answer (score 1):

1. `scanf("%s", &username);` is not correct. It shall be `scanf("%s", &username[0]);` One should give concentration to the warnings especially for array/pointers involved.
2. Similarly below 2 lines

   `scanf("%s", &pass[0]);
   scanf("%s", &fullName[0]);`
3. `fprintf(p, "%s\n%s\n%s", username, fullName, pass);` You writing the fullname as second line, but while reading, you read 2nd line as password. So `fprintf(p, "%s\n%s\n%s", username, pass,fullName );`
4. Another suggestion, after opening the file, the file pointer shall be checked for its validity. for some reason, if it returns NULL, then your program would crash.

Instead of simply trying compiling and getting the o/p, best way to debug this simple code is to sit down with pen and paper, try analyse what happens with each line

Answer (score 0):

A number of things that are wrong with your code jumped out at me. I tried to fix as much as I could. The following should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int signIn(char username[], char pass[]) {
    FILE *p;
    char user2[30], pass2[30], fullName[50];

    if (!(p = fopen("users.txt", "r+"))) {
        printf("Could not read from users.txt file\n");
        fclose(p);
        return 1;
    }

    int ret = 2;
    while (fgets(user2, 30, p) != NULL) {
        fgets(pass2, 30, p);
        fgets(fullName, 50, p);
        // you have written the fullName to the file as a third line, so you must check for this too
        if ((strcmp(username, user2) == 0) && (strcmp(pass, pass2) == 0)) {
            printf("\nUser and password correct!!!\n");
            printf("Logged in as %s", fullName);
            ret = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (ret == 2)
        printf("\nUser or password incorrect!\n");

    printf("\n\n");
    fclose(p);
    return ret;
}

int signUp(void) {
    FILE *p;
    char username[30], pass[30], fullName[50];

    if (!(p = fopen("users.txt", "w+"))) {
        printf("Could not write to users.txt file\n");
        fclose(p);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Username: ");
    fgets(username, 30, stdin);

    printf("Password: ");
    fgets(pass, 30, stdin);

    printf("Full name: ");
    fgets(fullName, 50, stdin);

    fprintf(p, "%s%s%s", username, pass, fullName);
    printf("You have signed up!\n");
    fclose(p);
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    char username[30], pass[30];
    int choose;

    printf("Welcome to student login system!\n");
    printf(" 1: Sign in\n 2: Sign up\n");
    printf("--------------------------------\n");
    scanf("%d", &choose);
    getchar();

    if (choose == 1) {
        printf("User: ");
        fgets(username, 30, stdin);
        printf("Password: ");
        fgets(pass, 30, stdin);
        return signIn(username, pass);
    }
    else if (choose == 2) {
        return signUp();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** I apologize for the sloppy answer, I was not on my main computer. This code will work for reading 1 user.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &username);` Huh?? (hint: it's already a pointer...)

Comment: you declared pointers and not allocated memory. Example `char *username;` in signup() function

Comment: Whoops that was an oversight on my part. Wrote up the code the right way

Comment: @TannerBabcock, make sure you compile with ***warnings enabled***, that is `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for `gcc`, `-Weverything` for `clang` or `/Wall` for VS (`cl.exe`). You have 8 instances of mismatched or incompatible pointers. (all of which result in *Undefined Behavior*). If you choose `1` in your code as your first choice, it results in `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, if you choose `2`, Full name is skipped and garbage is written to the file. I haven't dinged you because I know you are trying, but you really need to check this code.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i have one problem now it making error on getline()  "undefined reference"